# как вернуть файл который приходит мне на сервер?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requests, response, buffer

Мне на сервер приходит xlsx файл, и мне нужно его вернуть не записывая никуда, а просто отдать файл клиенту.

```
  var optionsForXLSX = {
    uri: `${elasticURL}:${elasticPort}/*/_data?format=xls&source_content_type=application/json&source={"query":${JSON.stringify(source)}}`,
    timeout: 60000,
    json: true
  };

  const result = await rp(optionsForXLSX)
  ctx.attachment('doc.xlsx');

  ctx.body = result;
```

Если отправлять запрос с постмана по url который выше, то все ок, приходит xlsx файл который читается, но если через сервер идет, то файл открывается с такими символами 
s�
d

> �
>   d